# How to get image using XMLHttpRequest in javascript

Tags: javascript, .net

I need to show a image which is generating in another page. I am using XMLHttpRequest to get the image from that page. Not able to do this please help.

Code Block

This is used to get image

```
    Bitmap IMG = myPane.GetImage(700,700,92);
    //Bitmap finalImage = new Bitmap(800, 800);
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        IMG.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        stream.Close();

        byteArray = stream.ToArray();
    }

    Response.Write(byteArray);
```

This is used to fetch that in javascript

```
 function b() {
           searchReq.onreadystatechange = ProcessResponse;
           searchReq.open("GET", 'Default.aspx', true);
           if (searchReq.overrideMimeType) {
               searchReq.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
           } else {
               searchReq.setRequestHeader('Accept-Charset', 'x-user-defined');
           }


           searchReq.send(null);
       }

       function ProcessResponse() {
           if (searchReq.readyState == 4) {
               if (searchReq.status == 200) {
                   retval = "";                      
                   var img = document.getElementById("myimg");
                   img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," +(searchReq.responseText);
               }
           }

       }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to do so?

Comment: share the code that you have tried and what the problem you are facing

Comment: yes for reference I attach the piece of code

Comment: Why on earth are you using `XMLHttpRequest` to retrieve an image?

Comment: Does the other page generating also HTML or it's generating only the image with content type image?

Comment: No it will generate a bitmap of an image. I am using third party tool to generate image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use XMLHttpRequest. Instead, just set the src of the img element to your .net script:

```
function b() {
    var img = document.getElementById("myimg");
    img.src = "Default.aspx";
}
```

If this doesn't work because the browser thinks it's the same image file just add some junk query param to the url:

```
img.src = "Default.aspx?q=" + Math.random();
```

Comment: Note that the browser doesn't care about image extensions. It will pass the image to an image parser and the image parser will determine the type of the image based on the content of the image, not the file extension.

Comment: Thanks... But i need to load the image dynamically based on certain condition please help in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Image is a binary data and you have to modify some attributes of your XmlHttpRequest object in order to process binary data.

Mozilla's website has a good documentation about this subject here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

A code snippet from the above page does this:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "/myfile.png", true);
oReq.responseType = "blob";

oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
  var blob = oReq.response;
  // ...
};

oReq.send();
```

Comment: This was the trick for me oReq.responseType = "blob";

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `XMLHttpRequest` to retrieve your image. It can easily achieved by placing `<img>` tag like this:

```
<img src="myImageGenerator.aspx" alt="..." />
```

I'm assuming your script is on `myImageGenerator.aspx` page

Please note that `myImageGenerator.aspx` need to return the correct content type: `image/png`
You can do this in C#:

```
Response.Headers["Content-Type"] = "image/png";
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But i need to change the image part or portion based on some condition and i don't want to refresh/ post back my whole page. I am using .net 2.0.

Comment: Then you can use inline asp tags `<img src='<% =SomeCondition() %>' /> or the javascript way (slebetman's answer) or add`runat="server"` to your `img` tag and use it with C#